# Convertendo Web Scraper de Python 2.7 para 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping

Eu achei um script em Python 2.7 mas eu tenho a versão 3.6. Como sou novo nesse âmbito, eu queria trabalhar manualmente para converter esse script. Segue o código abaixo:

```
### Modified for naming pics by tag
import requests,urllib
import shutil
import re
import os
import os.path
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getnopages(noofpages):
for link in alla:
    href = str(link.get('href'))
    if href.find('page') >=0:
        currpages = int((re.findall('\d+',href))[-1])
        if currpages > noofpages:
            noofpages = currpages
return noofpages

def getlink(url):
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request import urlopen(url))
alla = soup.findAll("img")
for link in alla:
    href = str(link.get('src'))
    if href.startswith('http://images'):
        parts = re.search('(.*\/\d*\/)(thumb.*?(\d+\.\w+))',href).groups()
        href = parts[0] + parts[-1]
        item_name = "item_"+parts[-1].split(".")[0]
        atmp = soup.find("div",  { 'id':item_name} ).findNext('span', { 'class' : 'thumb-info-big' })
        if atmp == None:
            atmp = soup.find("div",  { 'id':item_name} ).findNext('span', { 'class' : 'thumb-info-small' })
        if atmp == None:
            atmp = soup.find("div",  { 'id':item_name} ).findNext('span', { 'class' : 'thumb-info-medium' })
        pic_ex = "." + parts[-1].split(".")[1]
        pic_name = atmp.contents[-2].string
        print ("href")
        downloadable.append([href, pic_name, pic_ex])


def downloadfiles(downloadable):
no = 0
DEFAULT_DIRECTORY = str(os.getcwd()) + "/pics"
os.chdir(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY)
for item in downloadable[0:]:
    pic_url = item[0]
    pic_name = item[1]
    pic_ex = item[2]
    print(item)
    print (str(no) + " from " + str(len(downloadable)) + " pictures")
    response = requests.get(pic_url, stream=True)
    outputDirectory = pic_name
    if not os.path.exists(outputDirectory):
        os.makedirs(outputDirectory)
    os.chdir(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY +"/" + outputDirectory)
    with open(pic_name+str(time.time())+pic_ex, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    os.chdir(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY)
    no+=1
    del response


#url = 'http://wall.alphacoders.com/search.php?search=avril&page=1'
#url = 'http://wall.alphacoders.com/by_collection.php?id=565&page=1'
url = 'http://wall.alphacoders.com/by_category.php?id=7&name=Celebrity+Wallpapers&page=1'
baseurl = url[0:url.find('page=')+5]
print(baseurl)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
alla = soup.find_all("a")
noofpages = -1
noofpages = getnopages(noofpages)
print(noofpages)
downloadable = [] 

for each in range(1,noofpages):
getlink (baseurl+str(each))
print(len(downloadable))
print (str(each) + " from " + (str(noofpages) + " pages"))

downloadfiles(downloadable)
```

Onde eu consigo uma base com as equivalências de comandos?

---

**Update 1:**

Eu revisei o código e corrigi a maioria dos erros de sintaxe do código, mas eu ainda estou enfrentando problemas nas últimas linhas:

```
for each in range(1,noofpages):
getlink (baseurl+str(each))
print(len(downloadable))
print (str(each) + " from " + (str(noofpages) + " pages"))
```

Ele acusa erro de sintaxe no `getlink`, então eu fiz a seguinte mudança:

```
for each in range(1,noofpages):
print(getlink(baseurl+str(each)))
print(len(downloadable)
print(str(each) + "from" + (str(noofpages) + "pages"))
```

Ainda assim ele continua acusando erro de sintaxe no próprio

Comment: não seria interessante você tentar rodar isso e ir trazendo os erros que vão acontecendo?

Comment: Oi Guilherme!  

Posso fazer isso sim! Como era minha primeira pergunta, decidi não arriscar muito, mas já tinha pensado nessa possibilidade.

@ Edit:

Para começar, eu ganho um belo "Invalid Sythax" na linha 19, função import:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request import urlopen(url))

A princípio eu pensei que fosse a urllib, mas não vi nada errado ali. Alguma idéia?

Comment: retira o urlib e usa requests para trazer o html  e usa ou soup para pegar o html, ai usa prettify e filtra pelo id q vc quer